# App State Preservation and Restoration in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I need to implement the status preservation protocol in my monotouch app, like described in the Apple Docs:

[App State Preservation and Restoration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH11-SW13)

But I cannot find any documentation or project sample on the Xamarin website about the UIViewControllerRestoration Protocol.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This protocol is not currently bound in MonoTouch. There is a bug for it here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8778

That said, there is a similar callback in the AppDelegate, application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder: that is bound in MonoTouch to the method:

UIViewController GetViewController (UIApplication application, string[] restorationIdentifierComponents, NSCoder coder).

This will be called once for each saved controller that has no restoration class set. Therefore, in lieu of the restoration class, you could override this method in the App Delegate.